# How to validate laravel validation rules using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, laravel, rules

I have been searching to find a good working plugin for jquery validation for laravel which should use the laravel rules defined in ForRequest or Controller. 
But could not find any working one.

I tried "laravel-jsvalidation" but not working fine. It submits the form even if empty field error showing.

Also tried parsley and then parsley extra (which they say supports laravel rules) but not working.

Can anyone please suggest me a good plugin already made.

THANKS
Faysal

Comment: I am new to Laravel but surprised i there no such plugin already there?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this package do the trick for you. Works with Parsley and formvalidation, and use moment.js for properly manage date validations.

https://github.com/dragonFlyAdmin/nag

> This package converts FormRequest rules to inline data attributes in
>   your forms.
>
> Both Parsley and formvalidation.io take these data attributes to
>   handle front-end validation.

Comment: when adding request attribute in form tag, giving error
Form::open(['request' => 'YourFormRequestClass'])
    Form::open(['request' => 'App\Http\Requests\YourFormRequestClass'])